# Restore type before console loads functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, iterm2

This might be a far stretch- but I used to be able to start my `rails console`, and while it's loading (since it has to boot everything and we use some large apps- so it takes a while) I could begin typing the first line of code in. When it finishes loading, it catches up and has everything I had been typing loading in.

That sounds like a silly feature, and I hardly know how to even describe it, but I recently got a new machine and that functionality is gone.

I find it super frustrating, as it can take 5-8 seconds sometimes to load the console (I know there are other issues there) and I REALLY appreciated having the head start functionality.

Hopefully somebody knows what's going on here, as I'd really like to get that fixed. :)

Comment: Have you tried using [`spring`](https://github.com/rails/spring)? Not what you asked for, but it helps load console (and tests) faster.

Comment: Yeah, we're using Spring. It's just a very large project. :)

Comment: Sorry to jump in kind of late but check out Bootsnap (https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap). It helps load our huge app a lot faster in development mode. I now get an active console in a few seconds instead of waiting for what feels like 10 minutes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, and it was actually related to another console issue I was running into.

The issue was that the `readline` gem was not installed prior to Ruby.

The solution was:

```
# Reinstall Readline
brew uninstall readline
brew install readline
# Reinstall current version of Ruby
rbenv uninstall 2.3.0
rbenv install 2.3.0
bundle install
```

This resolved both the typing before the console finished loading, and re-enabled my access to the history in previous sessions.